# c++ vector list initializer not working with type converting constructor for my class

Tags: c++, boost, vector

I created a class with a a "type converting constructor" (constructor that takes a single argument of a different type). I'm not able to use list initialization syntax to create a vector of that class.

Wrapping my class within a Boost Variant somehow makes the same class work with similar syntax.

What is the minimum I need to do to able to add my class into a vector using list initializer syntax?

Full program:

```
#include <boost/variant.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;
using boost::variant;

struct S {
  string s;
  S() {}
  ~S() {}
  S(const string& _s) : s(_s) {
    // Type converting constructor.
  }
};

int main() {
  // This works.
  S x{"abcd"};
  cout << "x: " << x.s << endl;

  // Why does this not compile?
  // I'm trying to create a vector with a single element in it.
  vector<S> vs{"vec_abcd"};

  // This works.
  vector<boost::variant<string>> vnts{"vnt_abcd0"};
  cout << "vec: " << boost::get<string>(vnts[0]) << endl;
}
```

Comment: IIRC when you create a vector, you can specify size and (maybe) default item, in which case the syntax would be: vector<S> vs(1,{"vec_abcd"});

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to initialize vector, which has a constructor `S(const string& _s)` with the type `const char *` and as per the C++ Standard (SC22-N-4411.pdf) section 12.3.4 titled 'Conversions'

> 4 At most one user-defined conversion (constructor or conversion
>   function) is implicitly applied to a single value.

So ....

1. Convert/cast const char * to std::string `vector<S> vs{  std::string("vec_abcd")  }`
2. Initialize `std::string` followed by the vector. Two level of initialization would require two level of indirection with 2 level of nested brace initialization as in `vector<S> vs{ {"vec_abcd"} }`.

Comment: thanks! adding a constructor for const char* makes the code compile.

Answer (score 3):

You need another set of curly braces to use the `std::initializer_list` constructor.

```
vector<S> vs{"vec_abcd"};
```

Tries to construct the vector with a `const char[]` parameter which will not work

```
vector<S> vs{{"vec_abcd"}};
```

On the other hand initializes the vector with a single element initializer list.  Look at it like

```
vector<S> vs{{"vec_abcd"}};
            |^list data ^|
            ^ ctor call  ^
```

<kbd>[Live Example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/ba8322b36ea750d7)</kbd>

Additionally if you wanted to constrict multiple `S`'s in the vector you can use

```
vector<S> vs{{"a"}, {"b"}, {"c"}, ..., {"z"}};
```

Where each comma separated inner curly brace is for each `S` you want in the vector.

Comment: @MooingDuck You are correct.  I'll fixed it.  I thought through it a little too deep ;)

Comment: Would you know how boost::variant is able to do it?

Comment: @user3625974 Most likely `boost::variant<string>` is directly constructable with a string literal.  I haven't parsed boost enough to know for sure but that is the most likely cause.